# Помогите разобраться с firebase. 1 вопрос

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase, vue-router

файл main.js

```
new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
  created() {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        this.$store.commit('SET_USER', uid);
      } else {
        this.$store.commit('UNSET_USER');
      }
    });
  },
}).$mount('#app');
```

При перезагрузке, буквальное на пол секунды при обновлении, происходит отрисовка кнопок как для неавторизованного пользователя. Подскажите как можно исправить? Через async awain не получилось разобраться. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На пару сек. такое отображение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Исправить это можно только исправлением шаблона (firebase по сути не при чем, просто состояния UI рендерятся неправильно... их должно быть минимум три: инициализация/занят, неавторизован, авторизован. А у тебя их похоже всего два, либо смена состояния не по тому условию прописана).

Comment: Короче, в шаблоне предполагается либо несколько слотов компонента под каждое его состояние, либо в одном (дефолтном) слоте ветвление `v-if..v-else-if..v-else`. Если компонент конкретного назначения (не общий), то лучше конечно несколько слотов: это удобнее и компактнее за счет "поручения" логики состояний самому компоненту.